# howto receive media volume change notifications?

Tags: android

Is it possible to register a BroadcastReceiver or something to get notifications of media player volume changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Immediate value you can get if you use AudioManager

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(STREAM_MUSIC);
```

The only function that gives you opportunity to register broadcast receiver is

```
mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(audioBroadcastReceiver);
```

where audioBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver and must be declared in the application manifest.

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Where can I find the list of MediaButton events?

Comment: Based on your response I also found this:

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html

Comment: Great. I also found that link but forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: I don't get any events from the volume rocker on the phone, only from my headset. Should it be possible to get from the volume rocker as well?

Comment: Definitely. But first unplug your headset, to see if it works without it. Not sure if they are sent if you have headset and try to change volume using phone rocker.

Comment: Can we do this for the lock screen?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258688/how-to-detect-long-presses-of-the-volume-key-in-a-service