# How can a music app detect the volume keys when screen off in Android?

Tags: android, audio, volume

I play a song in background, and the screen is off now. I press the volume key, the volume of the music stream changes. How can it happen? I have searched for a long time for a solution about how to detect the volume keys press event when screen off, but I don't know how to solve the problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to the according broadcasts. see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763464/howto-receive-media-volume-change-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to control the volume of audio played through your app, make use of setVolumeControlStream() method. It directs volume key presses to the audio stream you specify.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```