# How to detect long presses of the volume key in a service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, algorithm, function

### I want to detect long presses in volume key in a service. Here are my options:

---

**A) Let the user control volume from the lock screen**

I wan't to detect if the user has held down the volume button in a service while the screen is off. I already tried (for 2 days) doing it with `contentObserver`, but the problem is that contentObserver detects volume changes, and volume doesn't change when the screen is off. Is there any way I can let the user control volume from the lock screen?

---

**B) Detect long press for volume button from service**

How can I do this? Are there any broadcast receiver's that I can use while the screen is off? Is there a way to implement the `dispatchKeyEvent` in a service?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154118/listen-to-volume-buttons-in-background-service), but for me the second answer doesn't work in the background. I think the easiest way would be option **A** because I already have everything set up for when the user changes volume, so can I let the user control volume from lock screen? If not, is there anything else I can do?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: got any luck there?

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 Nope :( Still didn't get an answer on how to do this...

Comment: where can i notify you if i got something? give me your contact. I am working on an Idea, maybe it will work. I am trying yet.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 I get a notification overtime you comment here, so if you figure it out just comment or post an answer.